# Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора на slider, отображалось значение, на которое наведен курсор?

Tags: python, kivy

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора на slider, отображалось значение, на которое наведен курсор? И как его вообще создать? Я прошу вас обойтись без использования properties, так как у меня не работает Cython и я не знаю, как решить эту проблему.

---

Вот мой код:

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Player>:
    orientation: 'vertical'



''')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

class Player(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        sl = Slider(orientation='horizontal',
                    min=0,
                    max=100,
                    step=1
                    )
        sl.bind(value= self.callback)
        self.add_widget(sl)


    def callback(self, intance, value):
        print(value)


class Audio_Player(App):
    def build(self):
        return Player()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Audio_Player().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ на ваш вопрос. Можете пользоваться, как обычным модулем  - https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/behaviors/hover_behavior.py